# babel-node param prefixed with "--" isn't passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments, babeljs

I have a npm start script `"start": "babel-node index.js"`
If I want to pass arguments to it it is working if I not prefix the arguments with `--`.

I want to pass something like `npm start --delete` to delete the content of a database.

I try to get the arguments via `process.argv`.

`npm start delete` passes the argument but `npm start --delte` isn't.

Is there anything I have to do to get this working or it is even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just using the standard Babel package, then piping the output into node? May not be ideal for you but may be worth seeing whether or not that works? Eg: `babel index.js | node --delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I have to do:
`npm start -- --delete` then the `--delete` is passed into my script.
For this specific problem it isn't possible any other way at the moment when not touching the current toolchain.